# How to see checked out file

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using SP Online. I am a site owner but I could not see a checked-out file (by another user). Checked out files are invisible to other users in my site. How can I see this checked-out file and the creator (of file) name?

Why am I asking this? I am trying to delete a folder and it wouldn't let me delete and saying this (see picture). It doesn't say who has the file checked-out.

[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This works well ONLY if your library has less that 5000 rows. I have libraries that are over that threshold. Is there any way to see the checked out files?

Comment: i get an error message saying "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An administrator can see all the checked files by going into the Document Library settings page.

In your document library, do the following:

1. Settings - Document Library Settings
2. Under Permissions and Management click on Manage checked out files
3. This will list all the check out files and if you choose to you can take ownership and check them back in

and also try to Add the Checked out column into your view.
simply go to the view edit setting,  add column **Checked Out To** into your view.

It will show all users to whom any document is checked out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, your answer helped. One my version, I had to access these files via the link on picture below

[image]

Comment: glad it works :)